# Git branches for Xcode targets

Tags: xcode, git

I developed 3 projects that, despite sharing 80% of the code, the way they get data is completely different. The sharing code is basically UI, helpers, some model classes, among others.

Now I have been able to create a single project that contains these 3 projects organised and structured by targets. I am also trying to achieve a branch creation for each target so, is there a friendly way to organise branches by targets in Xcode.

Maybe the question does not make a lot of senses. If so, let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by targets? Target population of users?

Comment: In Xcode a target is the "equivalent" of a flavour so: Flavour1 would belong to branch1...

Comment: Since *flavour* is not a metaphor any clearer to me here, I'll assume I lack the Xcode culture necessary to help you and let others answer. Good luck to you, Reimond.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.Thank you.

Comment: I thought about that and maybe your are right about the approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach is to put the 80% common code into a `.framework` that is used by the 3 apps.  The framework and the apps need their own git repo (so 4 total) and you can use *git modules* to import the framework repo into the app git repos.

Your approach is counter-intuitive as it's more conventional to have a separate git repo for each app and it can be fiddly to cherry-pick between branches if you are making changes to the common code.